# Unable to print output of JSON code into a .csv file

Tags: json, python-2.7, csv, parsing, web-scraping

I'm getting the following errors when trying to decode this data, and the 2nd error after trying to compensate for the unicode error:

Error 1:

```
write.writerows(subjects)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u201c' in position 160: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Error 2:

```
with open("data.csv", encode="utf-8", "w",) as writeFile:
SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg
```

Code

```
import requests
import json
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

r    = urllib.urlopen('https://thisiscriminal.com/wp-json/criminal/v1/episodes?posts=10000&page=1')
data = json.loads(r.read().decode('utf-8'))

subjects = []

for post in data['posts']:
subjects.append([post['title'], post['episodeNumber'], 
post['audioSource'], post['image']['large'], post['excerpt']['long']])

with open("data.csv", encode="utf-8", "w",) as writeFile:
write = csv.writer(writeFile)
write.writerows(subjects)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using requests and with the correction to the second part (as below) I have no problem running. I think your first problem is due to the second error (is a consequence of that being incorrect).

I am on Python3 and can run yours with my fix to open line and with

```
r = urllib.request.urlopen('https://thisiscriminal.com/wp-json/criminal/v1/episodes?posts=10000&page=1')
```

I personally would use `requests`.

```
import requests
import csv

data = requests.get('https://thisiscriminal.com/wp-json/criminal/v1/episodes?posts=10000&page=1').json()

subjects = []

for post in data['posts']:
    subjects.append([post['title'], post['episodeNumber'], 
    post['audioSource'], post['image']['large'], post['excerpt']['long']])

with open("data.csv", encoding ="utf-8", mode = "w",) as writeFile:
    write = csv.writer(writeFile)
    write.writerows(subjects)
```

For your second, looking at [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) for `open` function, you need to use the right argument names and add the name of the `mode` argument if not positional matching.

```
with open("data.csv", encoding ="utf-8", mode = "w") as writeFile:
```